# Go struct to represent twitter JSON result

Tags: json, go

I've bashed up this Go twitter client below, the client still needs some work in terms of displaying the results, I'd like to represent the JSON result http://pastie.org/7298856 as a Go struct, I don't need all the fields in the JSON result, any pointers?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type TwitterResult struct{

}

var twitterUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23KOT"

func retrieveTweets(c chan<- string) {
    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(twitterUrl)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        c <- string(body)
    }

}

func displayTweets(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go retrieveTweets(c)
    for {
        displayTweets(c)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/dNjIs-O64do which is enough to point me in the right direction. 
Update: my implementation of the code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type twitterResult struct {
    Results []struct {
        Text     string `json:"text"`
        Ids      string `json:"id_str"`
        Name     string `json:"from_user_name"`
        Username string `json:"from_user"`
        UserId   string `json:"from_user_id_str"`
    }
}

var (
  twitterUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23UCL"
  pauseDuration = 5 * time.Second
)

func retrieveTweets(c chan<- *twitterResult) {
    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(twitterUrl)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        r := new(twitterResult) //or &twitterResult{} which returns *twitterResult
        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c <- r
        time.Sleep(pauseDuration)
    }

}

func displayTweets(c chan *twitterResult) {
    tweets := <-c
    for _, v := range tweets.Results {
        fmt.Printf("%v:%v\n", v.Username, v.Text)
    }

}

func main() {
    c := make(chan *twitterResult)
    go retrieveTweets(c)
    for {
        displayTweets(c)
    }

}
```

The code works very well, I only wonder if creating a channel that is a pointer to a struct is idiomatic Go.

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @jwesonga Passing pointers via channels is commonly seen [as passing the ownership of the underlying object around](http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/). So what you do is, in fact, idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

The [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package offers a way to unpack JSON directly
into structs. The following example parses JSON content (a map) and assigns the fields to their 
corresponding targets identified by the struct tags. E.g., the key `"someId"` is mapped to the struct 
field with the tag `json:"someId"`. You can fiddle with the code [here](http://play.golang.org/p/oyvVSqcUpw).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Example struct {
     Id    int `json:"someId"`
     Content string `json:"someContent"`
}

func main() {
    var xmpl Example

    input := `{"someId": 100, "someContent": "foo"}`

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &xmpl)

    fmt.Println(xmpl)
}
```

You can find details on the syntax in the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).
Fields that are not mentioned in the struct are ignored by default.